# wxPython non-focussed context menu

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have been able to create normal popup menus (such as context ones) using self.PopupMenu(menu, pos) and constructing a menu however one issue I run in to is that whenever I pop it up (say when I change the text in a text box ala search such as in Google Suggestions or iTunes) it will change the focus to the context menu. This seems to be built into the PopupMenu system, is there a way to show a menu but not give it focus.

Examples

Similar to (but not exactly) SuperTooltip in wxPython Demo

What these are (but in wxPython) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-SW4

Right now it looks like I just should create it out of a dialog with no title etc.

iTunes [image: iTunes Search]

Google Search [image: Google Search Suggestions]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an autocomplete window. There's an article on this topic on the wxPython wiki here:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/TextCtrlAutoComplete

You might also find this article helpful:

- http://megamicrobase.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/adventures-in-wxpython-autocompleting/

Or perhaps this thread:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/tgQcNj0b1kY